# Cant open gnome-control-center?

Tags: gnome, settings, system-settings, gnome-control-center

When i click on system settings in the dash nothing happens. When i run the command `gnome-control-center` i get the following output.

> gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libgnome-control-center.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you please try to reinstall it?

Comment: Installed gnome shell 3.8 and updated packages. Since then its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloaded the deb file from here http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-main-amd64/libgnome-control-center1_3.4.2-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb.html

Works like a charm now